# Look for a substring in a file and comment that line and insert new line underneath the commented line

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to look for a substring `--port 1234` in a file and if the line is not commented then, comment out the line with `#` and insert a new line underneath it defined as `this is the new path: /new/path/to/file`. If the line containing `--port 1234` is already commented, then do nothing. If substring `--port 1234` is not found in the file then `echo "not found"`

Sample input:

```
somecode somecode
somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
somecode somecode
```

Sample output:

```
somecode somecode
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
This is the new path: /new/path/to/file
somecode somecode
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
sed -E '/--port 1234/!b;/^[^#]/!b;
```

so far I've only figured out how to ignore if the line is already commented, or if a line does not contain `--port 1234`. Very new to bash script!

Comment: You always ask the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367220/look-for-a-substring-in-a-file-with-multiple-occurences-and-comment-those-lines) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370442/look-for-a-substring-in-a-file-and-if-found-comment-it-and-insert-a-new-line-o) . Try by yourself and come here when you can't resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is more suitable for this job.

**Sample File:**

```sh
cat file

foo bar
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
somecode somecode
somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
somecode somecode
```

Use `gnu awk` as:

```sh
awk -i inplace '/--port 1234 / && !/^#/ {
   print "#" $0 ORS "This is the new path: /new/path/to/file"
   next
} 1' file

foo bar
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
somecode somecode
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
This is the new path: /new/path/to/file
somecode somecode
```

Comment: It just printed out the output(though correct) in the terminal but the file didn't change. I want the file to be edited itself!

Comment: What is your awk version? Check with `awk -V`

Comment: 3.1.7 is my GNU awk

Comment: in place is not compatible with 3.1.7. Can you try to use `sed` or `grep` please?

Comment: Then use: `awk '/--port 1234/ && !/^#/ {print "#" $0 ORS "This is the new path: /new/path/to/file"; next} 1' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`

Comment: @asfas: May I know why removed acceptance mark from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with the `sed` idea:

Sample input, with and without leading comment (`#`):

```
$ cat myfile
somecode somecode
somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
somecode somecode
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
somecode somecode
```

One `sed` idea:

```
$ sed -E 's|^([^#].*--port 1234.*)$|#\1\nThis the new path: /new/path/to/file|' myfile
somecode somecode
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
This the new path: /new/path/to/file
somecode somecode
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
somecode somecode
```

Once OP is satisfied with the result the `-i` flag can be added to perform an inplace update of the file.

Comment: This is a good solution but if I issue the `sed `command the second time, `This the new path: /new/path/to/file` is printed again. I don't want that. Could you fix that in your solution through  maybe grep or if condition?

Comment: I misread the part about the line being previously commented out; answer updated